# VB.Net - Automatic Update to the User

Tags: .net, vb.net, time, auto-update

I am designing an Windows application in Vb.net. When ever I run the application it needs to check the current time and remind me some tasks which I have defined. In what way can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your tasks somewhere (database, file, etc) and have a due date and time associated with them.

The when your application runs you find all tasks in your data where the due date is older than the current date and time.

For example if you were storing you tasks in a sql server database you could run a query similar to this:

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Tasks WHERE DueDate < @DueDate"
Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string here"), _
    cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DueDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While reader.Read
        Debug.WriteLine(reader(0))
    End While
End Using
```

That should get you started